# how to set checked attribute to a box in CheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that's populated and bound dynamically.  One column is a CheckBoxColumn.

How can I programmatically check individual boxes within that column?

Comment: @Muad'Dib: DataGridView is winforms. Updated the tags in the question.

Comment: it's bound to a winform if thats what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of the cell to `true` or `false` to check or uncheck it respectively:

```
// check the 2nd row
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = true;
```

If the column is not being bound to `bool` values, you can set the cell value according to the values set for [TrueValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.truevalue.aspx), [FalseValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.falsevalue.aspx), and [IndeterminateValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.indeterminatevalue.aspx) on the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.